# 'Ignoring exception in command None: discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandNotFound: Command "test" is not found' error in Discord py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import CommandNotFound

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('NCS is ready')

client.command()
async def test(ctx, test=str):
    await message.channel.send(account)


client.run("")
```

This is an example of what I want to make. It's a simple thing that repeats the second thing word you say. The only problem is when I write '.test', it doesn't work and I get this error:

```
'Ignoring exception in command None:
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandNotFound: Command "test" is not found
```

I know how to remove this error, but not to fix it. Can you please help me. Thanks.

Comment: There is no `@` beginning of your command, try it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to make the `command()` a decorator.  Also, you will want to use `ctx.send`, and your `account` variable is going to be undefined in your example:

```
@client.command()
async def test(ctx, test=str):
    await ctx.send(account)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you make a command, you should add `@client.command()` at the beginning. In your case, you forget to put `@`. So if you do, your problem will be solved.